# symfony2 doctrine2: remove entity class from which was used in the past migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

i am taking over an rather big and existing project. for the start i have to remove some entity classes and tables which are not longer used in the project.

the project uses migrations.

so i do: 
- remove entity class
- removed all references to this class in my code. 
- wrote a migration which drop the coresponding database tables.

problem is: some of the previous migrations referenced to the entity class.

question: 
- do i have to manually edit all previous entity classes? 
- do i do this process even right? how to remove an entity class in a later project stage at general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand well your problem, but that's how I remove an existing entity:

- delete or rename the entity (entity.php.old or whatever)
- remove all references to this entity (ManyToOne, use, etc.)
- `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff`
- `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

and it should be good, the goal of `doctrine:migrations` is to prevent issue with the mappping, it's strange that you cannot remove an entity because of it.

Comment: ok, so basically you say to remove the old entity by hand is a good practice. I thought at this point when I posted the question that there are some more fancy magic is going on :) Thank you!